# FreeType2 multiple faces

Tags: c++, opengl, freetype2

I'm implementing fonts rendering in OpenGL app using FreeType2 library.
My problem is that initializing more then one `FT_Face` objects crashes the program. I tried having single instance of `FT_Library` and calling `FT_Init_FreeType()` for each new font. I also tried havind separate instances of `FT_Library` for each font.
Both initializations work, but then I get assertion from `malloc.c` when I use `new` operator next time no matter where, literaly on the next line of code.

Here is the Font object creation method where FreeType2 lib gets initialized:

```
Font::Font* create(const char* path, unsigned int size) {
  Font* font = new Font();

  FT_Init_FreeType(&(font->_ft));

  if(FT_New_Face(font->_ft, path, 0, font->_face)) {
    std::cerr << "Font: Could not load font from file " << path << "." << std::endl;
    return NULL;
  }

  FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(*(font->_face), 0, size);
}
```

This peace of code works just fine if I call it once. If I call it for the second time and then somwhere later in another part of the program I create object via `new`, application crashes.

What is wrong here? There should be some good way for loading several fonts...

Assertion message: `malloc.c:2365: sysmalloc: Assertion (old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long)old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.`

**UPDATE:**

Font class declaration, version with ft library instance per class:

```
class Font
{
  public:
    static Font* create(const char* font, unsigned int size);
    void renderText(const wchar_t* text, float x, float y, float sx, float sy);

  private:
    Font();
    ~Font();

    FT_Library _ft;
    FT_Face* _face;
};
```

`renderText()` method basicly uses _face to peek required chars and render them.

Comment: Is there more than one thread in the program? Can you tell us more about your Font class?

Comment: Only one thread. Font class descriptions comes in a minute as update to the post.

Comment: What is in Font constructor and destructor? Why do you wrote  `FT_Face* _face` and `FT_New_Face(font->_ft, path, 0, font->_face)` instead of `FT_Face _face` and `FT_New_Face(font->_ft, path, 0, &font->_face)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before call `FT_New_Face`, are you sure the `font->_face` was new? So, you need new a `FT_Face` if `font->_face` is NULL.

**Note**: It is not necessary to init a `FT_Library` for each Font instance. You can make the `Font::_ft` to be static.

Finally, code should be:

```
class Font
{
public:
    static FT_Library      _ft;
    static Font* create(const char* path, unsigned int size)
    {
        Font* font = new Font();

        if (Font::_ft == NULL)
            if (FT_Init_FreeType(&Font::_ft))
                return NULL;

        if (font->_face == NULL)
            font->_face = new FT_Face;
        if (FT_New_Face(font->_ft, path, 0, font->_face)) {
            std::cerr << "Font: Could not load font from file " << path << "." << std::endl;
            return NULL;
        }

        FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(*(font->_face), 0, size);
        return font;
    }

private:
    // Set the member - _face to NULL when call constructor
    Font() : _face(NULL) {}
    ~Font() { /* release the memory */ }
    FT_Face*        _face;
};

// Set the static member - _ft to NULL
FT_Library Font::_ft = NULL;
```

At last, you need uninitialize/release all memory about FreeType2 when call destructor.

**Note**: The fourth variable (`FT_Face`) of `FT_New_Face`  must be instance. The `FT_New_Face` don't allocate the memory for `FT_Face`.

Comment: This looks like good implementation to me. It may be calling Ft_Init_FreeType more than once is causing the issue. In addition to Alex's solution, you may consider using the Factory pattern to ensure that for each font/size combination you instantiate only one object.

Comment: Sorry, that should be Flyweight pattern.

Comment: I finally got it working. The problem disappeared when I turned _face into a variable, not the pointer. I can't imagine what could go wrong with it. Anyway, thank you for advices, having sinle instance of FT_Library sounds really logical. I'll be glad to mark your answer as accepted if you have an explanation for the strange behaviour of the FT_Face as pointer. Otherwise I'll have breake the rules of SO :)

Comment: Great, I will try to do my best. But I said ' So, you need new a `FT_Face` if `font->_face` is NULL.', it means `FT_Face` must be instance in `FT_New_Face`. Sorry, my bad English.